# Wrong output for SFINAE member detect in MSVC2015

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I was learning about SFINAE and how to easy implement it with `void_t`. But I get different output for different compilers:

```
//pre c++17 void_t definition:
template<class... Ts> struct make_void {typedef void type;};
template<class... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

//check for member helper structures
template<class, class = void>
struct has_abc : std::false_type
{ };

template<class T>
struct has_abc<T, void_t<decltype(T::abc)>> : std::true_type
{ };

class has
{
public:
    void abc();
};

class has_not
{ };

int main()
{
    std::cout << has_abc<has>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << has_abc<has_not>::value << std::endl;
}
```

GCC 5.3.0 prints expected output `1 0`, but MSVC 2015 prints `0 0`, why?

---

EDIT:

Additional example with working GCC 5.3.0 code that supposedly violates c++ syntax:

```
template<class T>
void test()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(T::func), void(T::*)(void)>::value << std::endl;
}

class Test
{
public:
    void func();
};

int main()
{
    test<Test>();
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Just curious, why dont you define `void_t` as : `template<typename...> using void_t = void;` What is the problem with that?

Comment: @Nawaz Some compilers shortcircuit it to `void` and avoid all the type instantiations.

Comment: @Barry: I thought that too. But is that allowed by the spec? As for *which version* of the spec, that would be an interesting question!

Comment: @Nawaz See [core issue 1558](http://wg21.link/cwg1558). That question was asked to death on SO when Walter Brown gave his `void_t` talk at CppCon two years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there is an error with your code. MSVC is right while GCC is simply wrong.

The syntax for pointer to member function doesn't work like that. You **have** to put the `&` in front of the expression:

```
//check for member helper structures
template<class, class = void>
struct has_abc : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct has_abc<T, void_t<decltype(&T::abc)>> : std::true_type {};
//     Notice the '&' there ------^
```

The syntax for `T::member` only work with static data member, and `typename T::member` work for member types. While working with sfinae, it's important to distinguish small syntax properties and differences.

As a request in the comment, here's multiple statement that shows that non static member cannot be referenced without the `&` with GCC 5.3: https://godbolt.org/g/SwmtG2

Here's an example with GCC: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ee57c2c34b32753

Here's an example with MSVC: http://rextester.com/FJH22266

Here's the section from the C++ standard that explicitly state that without the `&`, the expression is not well formed:

[[expr.prim.id]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.id#2)

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access ([expr.ref]) in which the object expression refers to the member's class or a class derived from that class,
> - or to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), or
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand. [ Example:

-

> ```
>  struct S {
>    int m;
>  };
>
>  int i = sizeof(S::m);           // OK
>  int j = sizeof(S::m + 42);      // OK
> ```
>
> — end example ]

---

As we discussed in the chat, we concluded that the reason there is a difference with the two compilers is that both GCC and MSVC has bugs that prevent this code to work well. As mentionned, MSVC will refuse to apply the SFINAE rule if there is an unrelated class that don't implement the rule correctly: http://rextester.com/FGLF68000

Note that sometime, changing the name of a type trait helped MSVC to parse my code correctly, but it's mostly unreliable.

Consider reporting a bug to microsoft and upgrade your GCC version if you want your code to work as expected.

Comment: Wat? How does that change anything. Still same output, and I'm pretty sure you can address member function without `&` - it's just class scope, not a call, that's different.

Comment: @EbisuDev Please, visit the example I added and see the result by yourself.

Comment: @Gaillaume Racicot It is true for GCC 4.9.3 and GCC 6.1.0, but not for GCC 5.3.0. Also note, that function has a type too, for example type `int(int)` is function type, it's not `int(*)(int)`.

Comment: @EbisuDev The expression `decltype(has::abc)` won't ever yield to the type `void(void)`. This is a bug if gcc is accepting it. The portable, working solution and the reason why you had difficulties with MSVC is in the answer I posted.

Comment: @EbisuDev I added the paragraph from the C++ standard, if that could help you understand why GCC 5.3 is wrongly accepting your code with the behavior you intended.

Comment: The problem is that your answer doesn't answer the question. Not sure what version of MSVC is in your linked example, but for MSVC2015 with, or withour `&` output is still `0 0`, and for GCC 5.3.0 with, or without `&` (again) it's `1 0`. After all you have written, I still don't know WHY does this happen for given versions of compilers. I'll edit my question with additional example for GCC 5.3.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123560/discussion-between-guillaume-racicot-and-ebisu-dev).

Comment: The applicable quote is [\[expr.prim.id\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.id#2)

Answer (score 0):

this way  works:

```
template<class T>
struct has_abc<T, void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().abc())>> : std::true_type
{ };
```

Comment: Working solution, but won't work for members that don't have `operator()`, for example built-in types.